# Entity Framework: Reusing foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys

I'm refactoring someone else's code involving EF6, code-first. I am trying to reuse database columns so that they are involved in more than one foreign key relationship.

I am aware that by doing this, I am denormalizing my schema, but in so doing, it will allow me to make more direct relationships between models that were missing in the original design. I would like this to happen with minimal changes to the underlying database schema, as there are hand-written sprocs and UDFs that will be affected.

The models below represent the current state of affairs:

A `Frame` is comprised of a `FrameType` and a `Moulding`. Frames are unique, in that no pair of `FrameType` or `Moulding` is repeated, so we have a composite primary key over `FrameType_Id` and `Moulding_Id`.

```
public class Frame
{
    [Key,Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Moulding")]
    public int Moulding_Id { get; set; }
    public Moulding Moulding { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("FrameType")]
    public int FrameType_Id { get; set; }
    public FrameType FrameType { get; set; }
}
```

where we can assume a minimal implementation for `FrameType` and `Moulding`

```
public class FrameType
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public ICollection<Frame> Frames{get; set;}
}

public class Moulding
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public ICollection<Frame> Frames{get; set;}
}
```

Elsewhere we have a `Product` which references both `FrameType` and `Moulding`:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id{get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("Moulding")]
    public int Moulding_Id { get; set; }
    public Moulding Moulding { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FrameType")]
    public int FrameType_Id { get; set; }
    public FrameType FrameType { get; set; }
}
```

but, critically, does not directly reference `Frame`.

I would like to add a property to `Frame`:

```
public ICollection<Product> Products{get; set;}
```

and on `Product`:

```
public Frame Frame{get; set;}
```

re-using the `Moulding_Id` and `FrameType_Id` fields not only as foreign keys to `Moulding` and `FrameType` but also as a composite foreign key directly to `Frame`.

Is this kind of "reuse" of foreign keys possible in EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The only EF6 requirements are (1) the referenced entity property to be a PK, and (2) in case of reusing the parts of the FK, the FK properties to be *explicitly* defined, since there is no way to map 2 shadow properties to one and the same name. Fortunately your sample model satisfies both conditions.

I personally prefer the fluent configuration, because it's more explicit and IMO easier to follow. Or in case you prefer data annotations, decorate the *navigation property* with the `ForeignKey` attribute rather than the inverse, because while bot allow mapping a single FK field, the former is the only way to map the composite FK fields through data annitation.

Applying it to your sample model looks like this:

```
public class Frame
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Moulding_Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int FrameType_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Moulding_Id")]
    public Moulding Moulding { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FrameType_Id")]
    public FrameType FrameType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Moulding_Id { get; set; }

    public int FrameType_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Moulding_Id")]
    public Moulding Moulding { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FrameType_Id")]
    public FrameType FrameType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Moulding_Id,FrameType_Id")]
    public Frame Frame { get; set; }
}
```

However, there is a small issue - the above introduces a multiple cascade paths and normally would require you to turn cascade delete off. Which in turn will require fluent configuration, and once you use fluent configuration, there is no need of `ForeignKey` data annotation, so remove it from `Product.Frame` property and use the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Frame)
    .WithMany(e => e.Products)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Moulding_Id, e.FrameType_Id })
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Wonderful. Makes good sense. It's getting late here, so I won't get a chance to look into this until the AM. I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks.

Comment: Worked a treat. We have cascading deletes turned off globally, so I was able to stick to the attribute configuration. Moving the `[ForeignKey]` from the `id` property to the navigation property was the required insight. Thanks for your help.